# How To move window in right bottom in Kubuntu 20.04

Tags: kubuntu, shortcut-keys, window

i love to
move a window in left/right top/bottom by shortcut.

for left/right/top/bottom it works.

i use at the moment:

<kbd>Meta</kbd> + <kbd>left</kbd>/<kbd>right</kbd>/<kbd>top</kbd>/<kbd>bottom</kbd>

so i want have for e.g.:

<kbd>Meta</kbd> + <kbd>num pad 3</kbd> for move to bottom right

Comment: Which OS / Desktop Environment?

Comment: Kubuntu 20.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.68.0
Qt Version: 5.12.8

Comment: Meta key is tricky in some combinations as far as I've seen, less so with something like Meta-Alt-Some_key. As I want to use one hand for that, and on my laptop I have just one Meta to the left, while the arrows are to the right, I've mapped them all to the left side and use Alt-Meta-C for what you ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing your desired combination in Kubuntu 20.04 it works fine, so I imagine you want to know where are the keyboard settings. In this version they are under *System Settings - Global Shortcuts - Kwin*.

[image]

Meta key is tricky in some combinations as far as I've seen, less so with something like Meta-Alt-Some_key. As I want to use one hand for that, and on my laptop I have just one Meta to the left, while the arrows are to the right, I've mapped them all to the left side and use Alt-Meta-C for what you ask. But your combination should work too.